# Trying to make a prediction model in R

Tags: r

Collected several questions during the last days of programming. Trying to make a program that make a prognosis on how much money I get after working for 5 years.
One problem is when I try to take the money in minus money out.

```
moneyover.year[i] =  moneyin.year[i] - moneyout.year[i]
```

Then it gives this error: "non-numeric argument to binary operator"

I would like to extract information from each year with the function "summary" but it doesn't really work... It just shows:

> Length Class  Mode    [1,] 100    -none- numeric

Finally I want to predict how many holidays I will get.
The graph works but I want to get the percentage sign on y-axis.
Preferably a smooth curve with the histogram.

Here is the full code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(mc2d)
library(scales)
moneyin.year= NULL # Is there a work around this?
moneyout.year= NULL # Is there a work around this?
moneyover.year = NULL # Is there a work around this?
n=100

for (i in 1:5 ) {
  moneyin.year[i] <- list(rpert(n, min=20000, mode=23000, max=30000, shape=30))
  moneyout.year[i] <- list(rpert(n, min=10000, mode=12500, max=19500, shape=20))
  moneyover.year[i] =  moneyin.year[i] - moneyout.year[i] # GIVES ERROR!
}
moneyin.year
moneyout.year
moneyover.year # GIVES ERROR!

#graph = moneyover.year[1]
graph = moneyin.year[1]
summary(graph) # Doesnt really work...
sd(graph) # GIVES ERROR!
var(graph) # GIVES ERROR!

p <- ggplot(data.frame(graph), aes(x = graph))  
p <- p + geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), color="black", binwidth = 500, fill = "steelblue") 
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
p <- p + xlab("EUR") + ylab("Percent")
p <- p + theme_bw() 
print(p)


extraholidays = dpois(20:50,30)
barplot(extraholidays,names=20:50,xlab='Days',ylab='Percentage') 
# How to get "%" sign???
# How to get a smooth line?
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  This question isn't quite [reproducible](stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) since there are some functions definitions missing (e.g. `rpert`), and it's hard to help without knowing what your code does.  Please include the calls to `library` or the definition of `rpert` if it's a user-defined question.

Comment: Sorry! I started programming in R few days ago. Now they are included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an error when you call `moneyover.year[i] = blah blah blah` because you haven't initialized `moneyover.year` and you cant take or assign to the subset of a vector that doesn't yet exist.  (you initilized `moneyover` and not `moneyover.year`...).

Initilization is just a fact of programming, but you can use multiple assignment to initialize several variables at once, as in:

```
moneyin.year <- moneyout.year <- moneyover.year <- NULL
```

The second error has to do with R's type conversion. Specifically, in the first iteration of the for loop, this line`moneyin.year[i] <- list(blah blah blah)` coerces `moneyin.year` to a list.  This is a problem when this line is evaluated:

```
moneyover.year[i] =  moneyin.year[i] - moneyout.year[i]
```

because the single bracket operator (`[`) returns a sub-list, and not the first element of the list.   This is a problem because the minus operator (`-`) is not defined for lists (hence, the somewhat non-intuitive error "non-numeric argument to binary operator").  Instead, you want to use the double-bracket operator (`[[`) which returns the value stored in the `i`'th element of the list.  as in:

```
moneyover.year[[i]] =  moneyin.year[[i]] - moneyout.year[[i]]
```

Since all three of the objects above are lists, it might save on confusion to initialize them as lists rather than as `NULL` values, as in:

```
moneyin.year <- moneyout.year <- moneyover.year <- list()
```

Comment: True but even with moneyover.year it gives a error.

Comment: THANKS! 
summary(graph) error was solved by summary(unlist(moneyover.year)). Now everything is almost done except the last two questions. That is: "How to get "%" sign and how to get a smooth line in Poisson distribution. Do you know how to solve them?